# Google sheets importhtml xpath

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I would like to scrap data from [this page](https://m.tipsport.sk/prematch/match/2921022/events), however, I can't get right xpath for `=importxml` function.

I would like to get span class `name` and `rate`.
E.g.

```
column A, column B
Robert Mistrík, 2.5
```

Do you know what xpath should I create?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get the name

```
//span[@class='name']
```

And this is how you can extract the rating for particular font

```
//span[@class='name'][contains(.,'Róbert Mistrík')]/following-sibling::span[@class='rate']
```

If you need to extract all the font and its correspondent values then you need to first find the font name using `//span[@class='name']` one you get the font name e.g. `Róbert Mistrík` then you have to pass the same in contains method of `//span[@class='name'][contains(.,'Róbert Mistrík')]/following-sibling::span[@class='rate']` xpath.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your time and answer. That's the way I thought it should work, but actually it isn't. :-(. If you try `=IMPORTXML("https://m.tipsport.sk/prematch/match/2921022/events","//span[@class='name']")` it just returns #N/A.

Comment: And what about this one `=IMPORTXML("https://m.tipsport.sk/prematch/match/2921022/events","//span[@class='name']/text()")`

Comment: Same. It returns #N/A :-(